# Phantom sales_order_place_after event fired without order?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

I have written a custom module which handles the export of new orders to a remote location.

The module has an observer set against the `sales_order_place_after` event and the function starts with the following log:

```
public function sendOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log('sendOrder() called for order #'.$order->getIncrementId(), Zend_Log::INFO, 'orders.log', true);

    ...
}
```

I have just noticed that there is a log of an order number for an order which does not exist in the system.

So my question is: How can this event fire without there being an order in the system?

Answer (score 2):

`sales_order_place_after` naturally fires when after an order has been completely placed. However, it's possible that you have a custom extension that happens to fires it as well (nothing else should be dispatching this event).

Do a string search for `sales_order_place_after` in your `app` directory and let us know what you find but only report back the `.php` and `config.xml` finds.

Comment: I can't see anything out of the ordinary, the two from core are `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc` and `app\code\core\Mage\SalesRule\etc` and then the one from my custom module

Comment: Only check `.php` files. You should be getting a hit ***only*** in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`.

Comment: Whoops missed that one, yes that is there as well - in the 'usage in string constants' section of the search. I don't have any other instance of it appearing (search from root folder, phpstorm) and I did a full download from the server before the search so I know nothing else has been installed remotely via the connect manager which I could be missing.

Comment: Hm weird. Maybe you have another observer defined that invokes `sendOrder` accidentally? As in, you defined an observer to hook onto another event, but in the `method` node, you put `sendOrder`. I don't see any other possibilities. Check your `config.xml` that has the order event.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any other reference, just the one `<method>sendOrder</method>` call from my module

Comment: Hm, very puzzling.. I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

invoke,use `checkout_submit_all_after` event instead of `sales_order_place_after`

```
public function sendOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log('sendOrder() called for order #'.$order->getIncrementId(), Zend_Log::INFO, 'orders.log', true);
return true;

}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, is there a reason why `checkout_submit_after_all` is better?

Comment: because of sales_order_place_after event only call when we call $OrderOb->place(); This function is call as per as business rules..It call depends on payment method.But checkout_submit_after_all is depends on payment method.Always call when order placed

Comment: Hi Amit, The issue is not that the event is not being fired in some instances, the site in question only has one payment method (on account), my issue is where the event appears to be fired without an order, I'm not sure how changing to this other function will help me find out why this is happening?